# What is the difference between jsdom.env() and jsdom.jsdom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am still foggy about how to used jsdom. What is the difference between jsdom.env() and jsdom.jsdom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The readme file](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#readme) explains that

> jsdom.env is built for ease of use, which is rare in the world of the DOM! Since the web has some absolutely horrible javascript on it, as of jsdom 0.2.0 jsdom.env will not process external resources (scripts, images, etc). If you want to process the javascript use one of the methods below (jsdom.jsdom or jsdom.jQueryify)

Comment: Yes I totally missed that. Anyway after last night's experimentation and studying jsdom's code, I found that jsdom.env() allows you to _inject_ js files (external or local) which will be available the _done_ callback. jsdom.jsdom on the contrary is more low-level, it simply returns a data structure. You need to invoke `createWindow()` to get the `window` dom. To _inject_ js codes we will need to do some more steps (which can be seen in jsdom.js's `env` function).