# How to spy on javascript functions in a script that's injected into a jsdom for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, sinon, jsdom

I'm trying to test functions while developing a chrome extension. For my testing framework, I'm using sinon (to spy, mock, and stub), mocha, chai, and jsdom (to create a dom that executes my chrome extension background and popup scripts).

However, I can't seem to be able to spy on the functions in the script (background.js) that I'm injecting into the jsdom.

This is what I'm doing:

background.js

```
function searchTabs() {...}

searchTabs();

module.exports.searchTabs = searchTabs;
```

background.test.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var chrome = require('sinon-chrome');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

var bg = require('background.js');

var window;
var spy;

describe('background page', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        jsdom.env({
            html: '<html></html>',
            src: [
                fs.readFileSync('background.js', 'utf-8'),  // Inject script into jsdom
            ],
            created: ...,
            done: ...,
        });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        chrome.reset();
        window.close();
    });

    it('should call searchTabs', function () {
        spy = sinon.spy(bg.searchTabs);

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);  // This is not called :(
    });
});
```

I suspect the problem has to do with either an incorrect import/export or that the background.js script injected into the jsdom isn't wrapped by the spy. I'd really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this problem!

Comment: I suspect the following may shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605961/what-is-the-difference-between-jsdom-env-and-jsdom-jsdom

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You're requiring the background in the NodeJS context

```
bg = require('background.js');
```

and then in your test you apply a spy to that.

JSDOM however gets its own copy of the file through `fs.readFileSync` and executes it in a sandbox, separated from the NodeJS context - so you're not applying the fake there.

Besides that, judging from your provided example, the `searchTabs` function is already executed when you load (or require) the background.js - so applying a spy *after* the function got called wont get you the expected results.

What you could do instead is separating the function from the actual execution and apply fakes, inside the JSDOM sandbox, inbetween. That could look this:

*background.js*

```
window.searchTabs = () => {
  // I'm searching for tabs
}
```

*run.js*

```
window.searchTabs();
```

*test.js*

```
const fs = require('fs');
const chrome = require('sinon-chrome');
const {JSDOM} = require('jsdom');

const html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>';

const dom = new JSDOM(html, {
  runScripts: 'outside-only',
  beforeParse(window) {
    window.chrome = chrome;
  }
});

dom.window.eval(fs.readFileSync('background.js'));

const spy = sinon.spy(dom.window, 'searchTabs');

dom.window.eval(fs.readFileSync('run.js'));

sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
```

If you're looking for an easy way to load popups or background in JSDOM based on your manifest.json then [webextensions-jsdom](https://github.com/stoically/webextensions-jsdom) might be interesting too.